# Varnish direct request to internal ip

Tags: http-redirect, varnish-4

I have an hash configuration like this

```
sub vcl_init {
    new bar = directors.hash();
    bar.add_backend(server1, 1.0);
    bar.add_backend(server2, 1.0);
}
```

I would like to add a rewrite rule that if in the url there is a word it must redirect to one specific internal server

```
if (req.url ~ "/newsletter" ) {
   set req.http.x-redir = "https://" + "10.1.3.4" + req.url;
   return (synth (301, req.http.x-redir));
}
```

But this rule doesn't work because 10.1.3.4 is an internal ip not a DNS. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to use a different director backend (the internal server) if the request contains newsletter. Thats possible.

Example

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/newsletter") {
        set req.backend = newsletter;
    } else {
        set req.backend = default.
    }
}
```

See https://varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/advanced_backend_servers.html

But you cant do a 301, thats for the external request, while here we are talking internal routing.